# How to deal with input shape of Conv1D with keras?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been trying to train a CNN on a dataset.

So i built the following CNN :

```
model = Sequential()

num_filters = 8
filter_size = 3
pool_size = 2

model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, filter_size, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(Conv1D(num_filters, filter_size))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Where `X_train.shape = (28086, 98)`.

Then I compile my model and when I compute :

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=16, validation_split=0.2)
```

I get this kind of error :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 98]
```

I am quite new to this field, and I don't really know what does this error mean...

So if you have any idea or tips I'd be grateful ! :)

Comment: X_train.shape? please

Comment: @sarannns Oh sorry I will edit my post but it is : (28086, 98) and actually in my code I used `X_train.shape[1]` and not only `X_train.shape`

Comment: thanks. So which means, the number of time steps = 28086 and the number of features = 1 ? but from the error it seems like your num_features= 98

Comment: @sarannns actually I try to have 98 features and i indeed have 28086 samples

Comment: Dimension of input to Conv1D has to be 3D [batch_size,timesteps,num_features]